# knockout.js - click is not working?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have this bound list:

```
<table id="product_list" data-bind="foreach : listProduct">
<tr>
    <td data-bind="text:name"></td>
    <td data-bind="text:description"></td>
    <td><a data-bind="click:viewDetail">View detail</a></td>  
</tr>
```

And here the modelview :

```
var load = {
listProducts : function(){
        var self = this,   
        self.listProduct = ko.observableArray([]);
        product.get().then(function(resp){
              self.listProduct(resp);
              self.viewDetail = function(data){
                //some code here    
              };
        });
   }
}
```

Finally the binding:

```
ko.applyBindings(new load.listProducts(), document.getElementById("product_list"));
```

The first it's bind the first item of product and then show errorMessage:

```
Unable to process binding "click: function (){return click:viewDetail }"
```

So did I do something wrong? and how to fix it? Thank.

Comment: Why are you using listProduct for both the function name and the array?

Comment: @artm sorry, I edited

Comment: You're binding to the elements inside `listProduct` array but your `viewDetail` function belongs to `self`, i.e. `listProducts` function.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would recommend writing it. Hopefully you can find your answer by looking at my example.

```
<table id="product_list" data-bind="foreach: products">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: description"></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="click: $parent.viewDetail">View detail</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

  var viewModel = {
    products: ko.observableArray(),
    viewDetail: function(product) {
      console.log(product.name + ": " + product.description);
    }
  };

  ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("product_list"));

  $.getJSON("/some/url/products", function(data) { 

    // data = {"products": [{"name": "foo1", "description": "bar1"}, {"name": "foo2", "description": "bar2"}]}

    $.each(data.products, function(key, val) {
      viewModel.products.push(val);
    });

  });

});

</script>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/2nrrxnof/9/